# How to skin the arrow on PopoverPresentationController

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uipopoverpresentationcontroller

I have a PopoverPresentationController, which needs to have black background , I applied background color but the arrow doesn't get skinned or coloured, attached is the image how it looks . POPController has tableview in it .

[image]

Answer (score 0):

We are unable to remove arrow for popover controller. If you don't need arrow you need to customise your own view. If you want to change the background color

```
popOver.popoverPresentationController.sourceRect = btn.bounds;
popOver.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = btn;
popOver.popoverPresentationController.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
```